# skip columns while converting tab delimited text file to csv php

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to convert a tab delimited file to csv. The problem is its a huge file. 100000 plus records. And i want only specific columns from that file. The file is not generated by me but by amazon so i cant really control the format.

The code i made works fine. But i need to ignore/remove some columns or rather i want only few columns from that. How do i do that without effecting the performance of conversion from txt to csv.

```
$file = fopen($file_name.'.txt','w+');
fwrite($file,$report);
fclose($file);

$handle = fopen($file_name.".txt", "r");
$lines = [];
$row_count=0;
$array_count = 0;
$uid = array($user_id);
if (($handle = fopen($file_name.".txt", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, "\t")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        if($row_count>0)
        {
            $lines[] = str_replace(",","<c>",$data);
            array_push($lines[$array_count],$user_id);
            $array_count++;
        }
        $row_count++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
$fp = fopen($file_name.'.csv', 'w');
foreach ($lines as $line) 
{
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}

fclose($fp);
```

I am using `unset` to remove any column. But is there a better way ? for multiple columns.

Comment: This is nonsense. And why are you opening the input file twice?

Comment: I dont see an `unset()` anywhere

Comment: This process can be boiled down to the simplest programming principle.. which is 1) read card 2) insert to new file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly . Thank you for your reply. I am new to this. I am trying to make a code. I thought it would be nice if i could get some good suggestions on stackoverflow. I dont think rude replies could help. I said i am using it. I didnt said i used it on above code i mentioned. I tried it and it works. But i wanted to know a better solution if possible

Comment: Reading 100,000 lines into an array is dangerous. You will blow memory very easily. Specially as you then building another array in memory before writing it to the new file

Comment: Even your `str_replace(",","<c>",$data);` is looking for comma's and converting them to `<c>` so is the input file a tab delimited file or not?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am trying to get report from amazon mws and its sending me a tab delimited file. The thing is the file can be small or huge. I tried with a account which has around 10000 plus products. I wanted to know if this is a good way to convert that tab delimited file to csv. and then i am importing the whole csv into db via mysql query. But apart from that i wanted to skip some columns which i dont need.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input file, just 10 lines or so

Comment: ofcourse i can.

Comment: can i share that on google drive or dropbox ? which suits you ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  https://www.dropbox.com/s/7n78t85igtgu63w/example.txt?dl=0 here is a example file

Answer (score 0):

I would do that by checking keys.  For example:

```
// columns keys you don't wanna skip
$keys = array(0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9);
$lines = file($file_name);
$result_lines = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $tmp = array();
    $tabs = explode("\t", $line);  
    foreach($tabs as $key => $value){
        if(in_array($key, $keys)){
            $tmp[] = $value;
        }
    }
    $result_lines[] = implode(",", $tmp);
}
$finalString = implode("\n", $result_lines);
// Then write string to file
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers,
Siniša

Comment: thank you for your answer. I would like to know if this is a good solution when i have a huge file ? Like with 10000 plus records

Comment: No it loads everything into an array, Memory will blow

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for clearing this. I appreciate your help on this by clearing this doubt of mine. Is there a good solution do achieve the conversion ?

Comment: I used to parse big csv/tsv files in order to import data to database and I do it similar way. You can have issues on memory limit, depends on your environment, if you are using shared hosting you can't control that setting from php.ini, but if you have some kind of VPS you can override that setting.

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form i.e. without worrying about removing columns from the output this will do a simple read line and write line, therefore no need to maintain any memory hungry arrays.

```
$file_name = 'tst';
if ( ($f_in = fopen($file_name.".txt", "r")) === FALSE) {
    echo 'Cannot find inpout file';
    exit;
}
if ( ($f_out = fopen($file_name.'.csv', 'w')) === FALSE ) {
    echo 'Cannot open output file';
    exit;
}

while ($data = fgetcsv($f_in, 8000, "\t")) {
    fputcsv($f_out, $data, ',', '"');
}

fclose($f_in);
fclose($f_out);
```

This is one way of removing the unwanted columns

```
$file_name = 'tst';
if ( ($f_in = fopen("tst.txt", "r")) === FALSE) {
    echo 'Cannot find inpout file';
    exit;
}
if ( ($f_out = fopen($file_name.'.csv', 'w')) === FALSE ) {
    echo 'Cannot open output file';
    exit;
}

$unwanted = [26,27]; //index of unwanted columns

while ($data = fgetcsv($f_in, 8000, "\t")) {
    // remove unwanted columns
    foreach($unwanted as $i) {
        unset($data[$i]);
    }
    fputcsv($f_out, $data, ',', '"');
}

fclose($f_in);
fclose($f_out);
```

Comment: Oh this seems indeed a good one. Thank you for suggesting this. But i do need to skip the data i dont need. As storing that in database would be waste of space. Is this something possible without effecting the speed ?

Comment: trying that now

Comment: Emm its always saying file not found even when there is a file there

Comment: there is a missing dot in this line ~ ($f_in = fopen($file_name."txt", "r")) === FALSE) ~

Comment: Also how to import this now previously using     $fieldseparator = ",";  $lineseparator = "\n"; what will use in your case ?

Comment: Sorry dont understand previous comment